# Spread Operator when setting State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object in default state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({name: "", products: []})
```

I have 2 Select elements with an onChange event handler:

```
<Select onChange={() => setData({...data, products: [...data.products, {id: 1, ...data.products[0]}]})})</Select>

<Select onChange={() => setData({...data, products: [...data.products, {...data.products[0], qty: 1}]})})</Select>
```

When I do a

```
console.log(data);
```

I get `{name: "", products[{qty: 1},...]}` only. How do I make this so the id is appended to the array as well?

Comment: Reverse the order of the first one - `...data.products[0], id: 1`. The spread is overwriting the `id` you set.

Comment: Change the first dropdown first so that you'll get a `products[0]` object with an id?